# Ruby on Rails installation ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

After using rails a single use, my rails seem to break. It gives me an error:

```
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/dasith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/dasith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

To make it work again, I have to run these commands:

```
rvm gemset create gemset_name    # create a gemset
rvm ruby_version@gemset_name  # specify Ruby version and our new gemset
gem install rails -v rails_version   # install specific Rails version
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and check first if your shell is a login shell. This makes a great difference. If you are not running a login shell, then this kind of thing will really happen to you all the time.

Comment: Its showing error in `rbenv` and gets solved when you run `rvm` commands. Which did you use to install ruby & rails?

Comment: I used RVM. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm. It was working fine, but when I downloaded a project from git and ran bundle install, it started doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It was an permission issue.

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username/.rbenv
```